# Running 10 Docker Spring Boot containers. Which parts of the applications are shared at runtime?

Tags: docker, spring-boot

Suppose we have 1 Docker engine. We want to split our existing monolithic software into say 10 Spring Boot JAR applications. Each application prints the message "I am application ". So we build 10 containers.

When these 10 containers run, how much memory does that consume? I think the memory of the shared openjdk8 image is shared, because it is an read-only image. Will parts of the Sprint Boot (standard) software also be shared?

Could I decrease the overall memory consummation by creating a 'standard' Spring Boot appliaction image?

Comment: 1. No, 2. No, 3. No. Each image runs contained and each will consume as much memory as it needs. It won't share anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @M. Deinum indicates - there is no sharing of image parts in memory.  @M. Deinum - thank you.

After investigating further: only on the disk there is sharing of read-only images.